# Rails unit testing model validation :inclusion fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, inclusion

Model order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :address, :email, :name, :payment_type_id
    belongs_to :payment_type

    PAYMENT_TYPES = PaymentType.pluck(:id)

    validates :name, :address, :email, :payment_type_id, :presence => true
    validates :payment_type_id, :inclusion => {:in => PAYMENT_TYPES}
end
```

Model payment_type.rb

```
class PaymentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :id

  has_many :order
end
```

From browser, validation works fine, if it is wrong it give an error, else go forward.
But problem is when I run `rake test:functionals` from terminal. Test didn't pass the validation. If I comment this line:

```
validates :payment_type_id, :inclusion => {:in => PAYMENT_TYPES}
```

all is ok. I don't understand why it is working in one plase, but in tests not ? ...

Fixtures are all ok.

Please help.

Comment: What is interesting some moment ago i run 'rake test' in terminal => no errors. 'rake test:functional' error from validation. Why ? )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is, that you are storing your payment types in a constant.

For your tests to work, the `PaymentTypes` have to be available in the database before rails loads your `Order` model, and this might not be the case.

One way to get around this, would be to use a (memoized) class method to store your payment types. As long as you access this class method after all your `PaymentTypes` are in the database, you should be fine.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :payment_type_id, :inclusion => { :in => self.payment_types }

  def self.payment_types
    @@payment_types ||= PaymentType.pluck(:id)
  end
end
```